# How are objects passed into a for...in loop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, for-in-loop

I'm new to JavaScript and am learning about for...in loops and objects right now. I'm practicing with the following example:

```js
let spaceship = {
    crew: {
    captain: { 
        name: 'Lily', 
        degree: 'Computer Engineering', 
        cheerTeam() { console.log('You got this!') } 
        },
    'chief officer': { 
        name: 'Dan', 
        degree: 'Aerospace Engineering', 
        agree() { console.log('I agree, captain!') } 
        },
    medic: { 
        name: 'Clementine', 
        degree: 'Physics', 
        announce() { console.log(`Jets on!`) } },
    translator: {
        name: 'Shauna', 
        degree: 'Conservation Science', 
        powerFuel() { console.log('The tank is full!') } 
        }
    }
}; 

for (let crewMember in spaceship.crew){
  console.log(`${crewMember}: ${crewMember.name}`);
}
```

The output of this code is that the console successfully logs crewMember, but not crewMember.name. crewMember.name is undefined, as in the image.
On the other hand, when I change the log statement to this:

```
for (let crewMember in spaceship.crew){
  console.log(`${crewMember}: ${spaceship.crew[crewMember].name}`);
}
```

the name of the crew member is logged successfully. I don't understand why I am able to access the crew member without going through the spaceship.crew in the first half of the console.log statement, but in the second half I have to go through spaceship.crew.

Comment: Are you sure this is the code you're using?  Because there's a syntax error...

Comment: if `crewMember` is a string (a *key* in the object), then it can't have properties. You probably want `spaceship.crew[crewMember].name`.

Comment: console.log(`${crewMember}: ${spaceship.crew[crewMember].name}`);

Comment: @David code fixed.

Comment: Spicy take: if you're just learning Javascript you shouldn't use `for...in`. It's got a lot of subtle behavioral gotchas. Use the static Object methods `Object.keys`, `Object.values`, `Object.entries`, etc. If this is for a course and you don't have a choice, then be aware that `for...in` will walk the prototype chain, and it gives potentially counter-intuitive results when used on arrays.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: think of "crewMember" perhaps as a alias/reference to the objects under `spaceship.crew` thus the need to use that alias reference as others have noted

Comment: @JaredSmith It is for a course, but this is good to know for the future.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers y'all! I'm understanding that `crewMember` works because it is a reference to the object which means it is "called" the same thing, but I need to access the object it self to get access to it's properties.

Comment: 1. make your `crew` an array. 2. inside the array put objects with `rank` property (`captain`. `medic`, ...). This way your code that iterates over the data will be cleaner. Arrays can be iterated with `for-of`.

Comment: I'm new to Stack Overflow and am so impressed and grateful by how fast you all responded...very excited to keep using this website in the future...

Comment: @WiktorZychla  Perhaps put an answer in showing HOW to remap/morph to that array structure from the EXISTING object since this is about processing that original object and all its properties - but keep in mind that is/was NOT the question even though your suggestion might apply to the original creator of the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comment.
The `for...in` loop fetches the property name as a `key`. So it's a placeholder for `captain` or `'chief officer'`. You can access a property via *dot notation* and *bracket notation*. Use brackets when using variables:

so:

```
spaceship.crew[crewMember]
```

That should work. See example:

```js
let spaceship = {
    crew: {
    captain: { 
        name: 'Lily', 
        degree: 'Computer Engineering', 
        cheerTeam() { console.log('You got this!') } 
        },
    'chief officer': { 
        name: 'Dan', 
        degree: 'Aerospace Engineering', 
        agree() { console.log('I agree, captain!') } 
        },
    medic: { 
        name: 'Clementine', 
        degree: 'Physics', 
        announce() { console.log(`Jets on!`) } },
    translator: {
        name: 'Shauna', 
        degree: 'Conservation Science', 
        powerFuel() { console.log('The tank is full!') } 
        }
    }
}; 

for (let crewMember in spaceship.crew){
  console.log(`${crewMember}: ${spaceship.crew[crewMember].name}`);
}
```

And as Jared Smith said in his comment, use static methods instead:
So put of the objects own enumerable keys in an array using `Object.keys` and iterate over them using `forEach` and a `Arrow function expression`.

```js
let spaceship = {
    crew: {
    captain: { 
        name: 'Lily', 
        degree: 'Computer Engineering', 
        cheerTeam() { console.log('You got this!') } 
        },
    'chief officer': { 
        name: 'Dan', 
        degree: 'Aerospace Engineering', 
        agree() { console.log('I agree, captain!') } 
        },
    medic: { 
        name: 'Clementine', 
        degree: 'Physics', 
        announce() { console.log(`Jets on!`) } },
    translator: {
        name: 'Shauna', 
        degree: 'Conservation Science', 
        powerFuel() { console.log('The tank is full!') } 
        }
    }
}; 

//Object.keys | return all the keys
Object.keys(spaceship.crew).forEach( crewMember => {
  console.log(`${crewMember}: ${spaceship.crew[crewMember].name}`);
});

//Object.entries | returns objects key and value in an array which you can iterate
  Object.entries(spaceship.crew).forEach( ([crewMemberKey, crewDetails]) => {
    console.log(`${crewMemberKey}: ${crewDetails.name}`);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone mentioned `Object.entries(` which can also be used to add clarity from a properly formed object by coercing them into an array-like object so here is an example of that for the `spaceship.crew` object we can use good names for `crewMembers` an then `crewMember` or just `member` some such which can add clarity of purpose and intent also when we do this.  Note this is less "brackety" since we have named properties of the objects.  Note how `crewMember` is an object then.

```js
let spaceship = {
  crew: {
    captain: {
      name: 'Lily',
      degree: 'Computer Engineering',
      cheerTeam() {
        console.log('You got this!')
      }
    },
    'chief officer': {
      name: 'Dan',
      degree: 'Aerospace Engineering',
      agree() {
        console.log('I agree, captain!')
      }
    },
    medic: {
      name: 'Clementine',
      degree: 'Physics',
      announce() {
        console.log(`Jets on!`)
      }
    },
    translator: {
      name: 'Shauna',
      degree: 'Conservation Science',
      powerFuel() {
        console.log('The tank is full!')
      }
    }
  }
};

for (let crewMember in spaceship.crew) {
  console.log(`${crewMember}: ${spaceship.crew[crewMember].name}`);
}
//console.log(Object.entries(spaceship.crew));

//console.log([...Object.entries(spaceship.crew)]);


[...Object.entries(spaceship.crew)].forEach((crewMembers) => crewMembers.forEach(function(crewMember, index, mArray) {
  console.log(crewMember, index);
  console.log(`At ${index} We have ${crewMember.name}: ${crewMember.degree}`);
  console.log(`And ${crewMember}`);
}));
```

Comment: Your code has some issues with the variable names.

Comment: It runs, but I specifically did a console log of the object `console.log(`And ${crewMember}`); just so it would show it is an object not a variable/string here.

Comment: I updated the `crewMembers` (collection of members) of which `crewMember` is a singular entity within that collection @Mouser  Thanks for the tip from a second set of eyes, names are important